# Boolean Type Property not working in WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: wso2, sendgrid, wso2-enterprise-integrator, sendgrid-api-v3, wso2-esb

I am passing **BOOLEAN** Type property value(see in code: **delete_all_contacts** property) to endpoint url which is not working in WSO2 EI 6.1.1. getting ERROR like **"delete_all_contacts' is  boolean required param"**.   i think it is taken as "STRING" type always even though property type is BOOLEAN.Please anyone help me to resolve this?

**Reference link:** https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/delete-contacts

API Code:

```
<api context="/contactapi" name="ContactAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/deletecontact?*">
             <inSequence>
          
          <log level="custom">
                <property name="===Delete contacts " value=" API Called===="/>
                <property expression="get-property('query.param.delete_all_contacts')/" name="===query.param.delete_all_contacts==="/>
                <property expression="get-property('query.param.ids')/" name="===query.param.ids==="/>
            </log>
            
            <property  name="delete_all_contacts" expression="get-property('query.param.delete_all_contacts')" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN"/>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.ids')" name="ids" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="get-property('Sendgrid-Config')" name="SendgridConfig" scope="default" type="OM"/>
            <property description="apiKey" expression="$ctx:SendgridConfig//*[local-name()='apiKey']" name="apiKey" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <header expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('apiKey'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
            <filter regex="true" source="boolean(get-property('delete_all_contacts'))">
                <then>
                 
                    <header expression="fn:concat('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts','?delete_all_contacts=',get-property('delete_all_contacts'))" name="To" scope="default"/>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="get-property('To')" name="===To==="/>
                    </log>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <header expression="fn:concat('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts','?ids=',get-property('ids'))" name="To" scope="default"/>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="get-property('To')" name="===To==="/>
                    </log>
                </else>
            </filter>
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="DELETE"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <default/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <respond/>
            </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="===faultSequence" value="Called=="/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
            </log>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**API Details:**

**URL**: http://localhost:8280/contactapi/deletecontact?delete_all_contacts=true

**Method**: DELETE

**ERROR Response:**

```
{"message":"'delete_all_contacts' is  boolean required param","parameter":"delete_all_contacts"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a stripped down version of your API and it seems to be working.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ContactAPI" context="/contactapi">
   <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/deletecontact?*">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="===Delete contacts " value=" API Called===="/>
            <property name="===query.param.delete_all_contacts===" expression="get-property('query.param.delete_all_contacts')/"/>
         </log>
         <property name="delete_all_contacts" expression="get-property('query.param.delete_all_contacts')" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN"/>
         <filter source="boolean(get-property('delete_all_contacts'))" regex="true">
            <then>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="===Inside===" value="Then"/>
               </log>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="===Inside===" value="Else"/>
               </log>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="===faultSequence" value="Called=="/>
            <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
         </log>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

However, I noticed that you have defined the resource method as `POST` and sending a `DELETE` request. Maybe that is causing some issues.

Comment: Hi @Arunan Sugunakumar,
Thanks for your reply. for me also it comes to required filter condition. the above mentioned error response comes from endpoint which i set into header mediator of "To" address. will try to change resource method and will  let u know